# Shading different on device and simulator

Tags: ios, opengl-es, shader

I have a GLKViewController embedded in a regular view controller displaying a spinning 3D model of one of my company's products.  I am using the same code in a different app to display another model and I have no problems with that one.

For some reason, when I run my current app on the simulator I get perfectly fine smooth shading as expected, but when I run on a device (I have tested on both an iPad 3 and iPad 4), I get what appears to be cell-shading, as though the lighting values are more discrete.

The real confusion is that this only happens when running on a device, and only to this particular model, not any of the others I have used.

[image: Running in the simulator]
[image: Running on the device]

Is there a known bug in GLSL that could cause this behavior?

**EDIT**

Interestingly enough, during my debugging, if I change

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(ambientColor.rgb + diffuseReflection + specularReflection, 1.0);
```

to

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(diffuseReflection, 1.0);
```

I get my desired output, but when I output each component, the remaining components all show up as just black, which shouldn't cause that strange shading behavior.

Comment: This sort of device-specific oddity in my experience usually come from precision artifacts. Are you using lowp or mediump precision in these calculations? What happens if you tinker with upping that to the next level of precision? The other thing I've seen cause black pixels are errors in the shader, like divisions by zero or overflows. These are sometimes handled in the Simulator and not on the device.

Comment: @BradLarson I was using many lowp variables in the shaders, but changing them to highp did not resolve the issue

Comment: @BradLarson How could I check for /0 and overflow?  there's only one division in my entire shader calculation (light attenuation)

Comment: Is there any possibility that the denominator in that division could be zero, or close enough to it to cause an overflow? You might be able to throw in a conditional statement and dump out a hot pink color (or something like that) if a bad case was hit. I've used that technique before to track down breakdowns in shader calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the filenames of your vertex and fragment shaders?

If you have a file named: "vertexShader.vert" and try and reference it using "VertexShader.vert" (note the capitalisation), this will work on the Simulator, but not on the device.

Comment: It definitely is compiling and using the correct shaders.  If it was a complete shader problem I imagine it would be a problem with all of my models, not just this one